# ios tableview text edit data lost when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am using UIview and added tableview.The api sending a data to show textfield in tableiveiw.I can show the textfield data in cell using coding bt the problem is when I scroll the tableview the text value is lost.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return subIncidentArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellapi";
    UITableViewCell *incidentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *dic = [subIncidentArray objectAtIndex:row];

    if (incidentCell == nil)
        incidentCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if ([[dic objectForKey:@"TemplateType"] isEqual:@1]) {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 300, 30)];
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.tag = 1;
        textField.text = self.contentOfTextField;
        [incidentCell addSubview:textField];
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        if ([dic objectForKey:@"TextValue"] ==[NSNull null])
             textField.text = [dic objectForKey:@""];
        else
             textField.text = [dic objectForKey:@"TextValue"];
    }

    return incidentCell;
}
```

Comment: that's because cells are re-used and your are re-creting the textfield. If you really want users to enter text into a table view cell, consider saving the text in an array and then repopulating the text field when that index is loaded.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.Please show some sample code.I am new for IOS app development..

Comment: When you say "the text value is lost", do you mean the value after you edit the text? or the initial value?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, it may work

```
  UITableViewCell *incidentCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
```

Comment: sure  i will do that from next time

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *incidentCell = [UITableViewCell alloc]init];
     NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
     NSDictionary *dic = [subIncidentArray objectAtIndex:row];
     if ([[dic objectForKey:@"TemplateType"]  isEqual:@1]) {
         UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 300, 30)];
         textField.delegate = self;
         textField.tag = 1;
         textField.text = self.contentOfTextField;
         [incidentCell addSubview:textField];
         textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
         textField.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
         if ([dic objectForKey:@"TextValue"] ==[NSNull null])
            textField.text = [dic objectForKey:@""];
         else
            textField.text = [dic objectForKey:@"TextValue"];
     }
     return incidentCell;
}
```

Try this this may work.

Comment: Not reusing the cell will affecting performance, especially if the data source is huge. Also, your code has two return, it should be only one return which is `incidentCell`.

Comment: @mahesh sorry not working...return cell was not in my code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, first of all be shure that your `subIncidentArray` is not empty in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. 
Try to re-init data of this array in this method